# Convexity of a function

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, convex-optimization, convexity, binomial-distribution

Let: $F_{j+1,y}(s)$ be the cumulative distribution function of a binomial distribution with mean $y$, $j+1$ independent trials considered for $s$ successes. Is it possible to show in any way that:

$\frac{1}{F_{j+1,y}(s+2)}-\frac{2}{F_{j+1,y}(s+1)}+\frac{1}{F_{j+1,y}(s)}>0, 0\leq s\leq j-1$

?

This can be helpful when comparing the expected value of random processes governed by poisson-binomial distributions against ones governed by binomial distribution. And in infer statistical dominance of a process over the other, indeed is a frequent term in bandit algorithms problems
Thank you for your kind attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Indeed, the cdf $F$ of the binomial distribution is log concave -- see e.g. [Theorem 2 on p. 152](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Advances_in_Stochastic_Inequalities/oksbCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=info:2QqHS8DHBXAJ:scholar.google.com&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover), used with $\alpha=1$, $r=\infty$, and $q$ being the probability mass function of the binomial distribution. So, $1/F$ is log convex on the set $S:=\{0,\dots,j+1\}$ of all atoms of the distribution. So, $1/F$ is strictly convex on $S$.

---

**Detail on the last statement:** Let $g:=1/F$, $i\in\{1,\dots,j\}$, $x:=g(i-1)$,  $y:=g(i)$,  $z:=g(i+1)$. We have $x>z$ and $(\ln x+\ln z)/2\ge\ln y$. We want to show that then $(x+z)/2>y$. But $(\ln x+\ln z)/2\ge\ln y$ means that $y\le\sqrt{xz}$ and hence, by the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, $(x+z)/2\ge\sqrt{xz}\ge y$, and the first of the latter two inequalities is strict, because $x>z$ and hence $x\ne z$. Thus, $(x+z)/2>y$.

Comment: Thank you @IosifPinelis ! Where do I find the reference that the reciprocal of a log concave function is log convex? It appears to me that the remark states for the pdf to be logconcave not for the cdf, am I missing someething?

Comment: @MarcoMaxFiandri : (i) That the reciprocal of a log concave function is log convex follows immediately from the definitions of such functions -- similarly to the fact that the function $(-f)$ is convex if $f$ is concave. (ii) A better reference than that remark is Theorem 2 of the same linked paper. I have also added details on this.

Comment: I see! I understood thank you for your patience! However I don't get how we retrieve the last inequality. Sure we've proved that (calling B_j the reciprocal of the cdf) $\ln(B_{j+2})-2\ln(B_{j+1})+ln{B_{j}}>0$ but this implies that the inequality also hold true for $B_{j}$?

Comment: @MarcoMaxFiandri : I have added a detail on this as well -- this is just the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: thank you so much I will acknowledge your priceless contribution in the article